# how to merge two htaccess files the first one is for the username and the second to hide php extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to merge this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

they are both in the root directory

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: yes but the problem is that it says username not found because it takes 'index' as a username